# Compound index not reducing docsExamined

Tags: mongodb, nosql

My mongodb database has documents for each minute for each device. I have a query that basically searches documents matching with month field.

```
    db.data.aggregate([
     {
       "$match":{ dId:14,month:6}
     },
     {
      "$project" :{
        dayOfMonth_agg :{$dayOfMonth : "$ts"},
        month : "$month",
        year_agg  : {$year : "$ts"},
        hour_agg  : {$hour : "$ts"},
        a0 :1,
        a1:1,
        d2:1,
        f0:1,
        dId:1
      }
    },
   {
    "$match":{year_agg:2017}
},
     {
      $group :{
        _id : "$dayOfMonth_agg",
        totalEnergy : { $sum: { $multiply: [{$subtract:["$a1","$a0"]},"$f0"] } },
        avg_d0:{$avg:"$a0"},
        avg_d1:{$avg:"$a1"},
        avg_d2:{$avg:"$d2"},
      }
     },
     {
       $sort:{"_id":1}
     }
   ])
```

I wanted to optimise query performance so I added compound index as:

```
db.data.createIndex({dId:1,month:1})
```

Now, in execution stats, docsExamined are equal to that of stats when single index on dId was created.
Exec stats with single Index on dId:

```
"keysExamined" : 103251,
"docsExamined" : 103251,
"hasSortStage" : true,
"cursorExhausted" : true,
"numYield" : 814,
"locks" : {
    "Global" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(1654)
        }
    },
    "Database" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(827)
        }
    },
    "Collection" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(826)
        }
    }
},
"nreturned" : 8,
"responseLength" : 770,
"protocol" : "op_command",
"millis" : 656,
"planSummary" : "IXSCAN { dId: 1 }",
"ts" : ISODate("2017-11-15T08:41:50.782Z"),
```

Exec stats with compound index (dId and month)

```
"keysExamined" : 103251,
"docsExamined" : 103251,
"hasSortStage" : true,
"cursorExhausted" : true,
"numYield" : 810,
"locks" : {
    "Global" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(1646)
        }
    },
    "Database" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(823)
        }
    },
    "Collection" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(822)
        }
    }
},
"nreturned" : 8,
"responseLength" : 770,
"protocol" : "op_command",
"millis" : 678,
"planSummary" : "IXSCAN { dId: 1, month: 1 }",
"ts" : ISODate("2017-11-15T08:45:38.536Z"),
"client" : "127.0.0.1",
"appName" : "MongoDB Shell",
"allUsers" : [ ],
"user" : ""
```

As per my knowledge, the docsExamined should have reduced in comparison with single index.
Why is it so?

Edit: Please refer to first comment for the answer

Comment: Aggregation pipelines cannot use an index in anything other than the **"first"** pipeline stage. So only `$match` or `$geoNear` or `$sort` applied as the "first" stage can actually apply an index. Since it's merely preceded by `$project` here it "hoists" the `$match` so an index can be applied, but since you change the document shape, there is no "month" field to be considered. So don't rename it to `month_agg` and simply leave it as `month`.

Comment: `"$match":{ dId:14,month_agg:6` should be `"$match":{ dId:14,month:6 }` and put it at the "start' of the aggregation pipeline. Add an additional `$match` after your projection "just" for the year conditions. I said all of this in the very first comment.

Comment: I am so sorry, I will do it now.